# Error while posting photo through facebook api only on IE9

Tags: ajax, facebook, internet-explorer, facebook-graph-api, image-uploading

This is a javascript function to make an upload of a photo to facebook, via facebook api.
It works everywhere, except in Internet Explorer 9

```
var sTagsPostcard =
    '[{tag_uid:' + sIdProfile + ',x:' + aPositonsTags[sIdLayoutPostcard][0] + ',y:' + aPositonsTags[sIdLayoutPostcard][1] + '},' +
    '{tag_uid:' + sIdFriend + ',x:' + aPositonsTags[sIdLayoutPostcard][2] + ',y:' + aPositonsTags[sIdLayoutPostcard][3] + '}]';

var the_url = $('input[name="hdnDomain"]').val() + 'media/postcards/' + sPathPostcard

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://graph.facebook.com/" + sIdProfile + "/photos",
    data: {
        message: 'MESSAGE',
        url: the_url,
        format: "json",
        access_token: sToken,
        tags: sTagsPostcard
    },
    success: function(data){
        if($('html').hasClass('touch'))
            $('form[name="frmCustomLayout"]').submit();
        else
            window.parent.location.href = 'https://apps.facebook.com/[APPLICATION_NAME]/?st=' + N_STEP_THANKS;
    },
    error:function(a,b,c){
        if($('html').hasClass('touch')){
            $('input[name="st"]').val(N_STEP_RESULT);
            $('form[name="frmCustomLayout"]').submit();
        }
        else
            window.parent.location.href = 'https://apps.facebook.com/[APPLICATION_NAME]/?st=' + N_STEP_RESULT;
    }
});
```

The execution enters the *error()* and not the *success()* function, and those are the parameters a,b,c:

- a: object error (or sth like that)
- b: error
- c: no transport

Any ideas for IE9?? thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The javascript ajax calling the graph.facebook api it seems not to work in browsers like IE9 / IE8.

The trick to solve it was to make an ajax call to a local script, and through that use the facebook api to do the same post.
In this way in all browsers the posting is working,

Comment: hello axel , do you remember how did you achieved this ?

Comment: @ᴊᴀᴠʏ at that time I used a PHP library to call Facebook API and javscript.